# How to prove that $\log(|f^{\prime}(z)|)$ is Harmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $f(z)$ is an analytic function of $z$ such that $f^{\prime}(z) \ne 0$. I want to show that $$\nabla^{2} \log|f^{\prime}(z)| = 0$$
where $$\nabla^{2} = \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}$$
Using  $$\nabla^{2} = 4\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}}$$
and the fact that $|z|^{2} = z\bar{z}$. I have been able to show that $\nabla^{2} \log|f^{\prime}(z)| = 0$.

Now if $|f^{\prime}(z)|$ is the product of a function of $x$ and a function of $y$, how do **I show** that $$f^{\prime}(z) = e^{\alpha z^{2} + \beta z + \gamma}$$
where $\alpha$ is real, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are complex constants?

Please any hint on how to approach the second part. Thank you.

Comment: $\log |f'|$ is the real part of $\log f'$ (at least locally if $f,f'$ are not defined on a simply connected domain) so it is harmonic as the real part of an analytic function

Comment: In the title you ask how to prove that $\log(|f'(z)|)$ is harmonic. Then you tell us that you were already able to show that, and ask a different question. That is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla^{2} \log|f^{\prime}(z)| &=&4\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}} \frac12\log\bigg[|f^{\prime}(z)|^2\bigg]\\
&=&2\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}} \log\bigg[f^{\prime}(z)\overline{f'(z)}\bigg]\\
&=&2\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}}\bigg( \bigg[\log(f^{\prime}(z)\bigg]+\log\bigg[\overline{f'(z)}\bigg]\bigg)\\
&=&2\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}}\log(f^{\prime}(z)+2\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}}\log\overline{f'(z)}.
\end{eqnarray}
Note
$$ \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}}\log(f^{\prime}(z)=\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}\bigg[\frac1{f^{\prime}(z)}\frac{\partial f'(z)}{\partial \overline{z}}\bigg]=0 $$
since $f'(z)$ is analytic; namely $\frac{\partial f'(z)}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$. Similarly the second term is zero. So
$$ \nabla^{2} \log|f^{\prime}(z)|=0. $$

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to do it with an approach similar to what you did. But do I solve the part that is, if $|f^{\prime}(z)|$ is the product of a function of $x$ and a function of $y$, how do **I show** that $$f^{\prime}(z) = e^{\alpha z^{2} + \beta z + \gamma}$$
where $\alpha$ is real, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are complex constants.

Comment: Can you help me with the second part of the problem?

Comment: What is $y$? Is $y$ the imaginary part of $z$?